# centering UIButton not working

Tags: iphone, ios, position, centering

When I try to change position of UIButton in my iPhone app it's not working.

I'm using code like this: `uxButton.center = CGPointMake(0,0);` but button stays where I've positioned it before on storyboard. I tried as well changing frame of this button. What can I posiblliy be doing wrong here?

Comment: Where are you calling the code?

Comment: sorry, my question was imprecise. I meant that I already have a button on the storyboard, and after the keyboard is shown, I want to change its position, to move it up...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will make a button at the center of your screen on portrait:

```
UIButton* xButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake((320-yourwidth)/2, y, yourWidth, yourHeight)];
```

if you want to make the button from storyboard set its frame:

```
xButton.frame = CGRectMake((320-yourwidth)/2, y, yourWidth, yourHeight);
```

EDIT with an example:

```
UIButton* xButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake((320-50)/2, 300, 50, 30)];
```

when your keyboard will show:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.6 delay:0. options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
    xButton.center = CGPointMake(xButton.frame.origin.x, 30);
} completion:nil];
```

this code will moves up your button

Comment: sorry, my question was imprecise. I meant that I already have a button on the storyboard, and after the keyboard is shown, I want to change its position, to move it up...